# Parsing XML file with elementtree: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python-2.7, elementtree

I'm trying to parse information from an XML file using ElementTree in Python 2.7.

The XML file has the following structure:

```
 <EXPERIMENT_PACKAGE_SET>
    <EXPERIMENT_PACKAGE>
        <SAMPLE>
            <IDENTIFIERS>
                <PRIMARY_ID>ERS1486582</PRIMARY_ID>
                <EXTERNAL_ID>SAMEA36350668</EXTERNAL_ID>
            </IDENTIFIERS>
            <SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES>
                <SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <TAG>collection date</TAG>
                    <VALUE>2011</VALUE>
                </SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
                <SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <TAG>geographic location</TAG>
                    <VALUE>USA</VALUE>
                </SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE>
                ...
            </SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES>
        </SAMPLE>
    ...
    </EXPERIMENT_PACKAGE>
</EXPERIMENT_PACKAGE_SET>
```

It contains many "Sample" modules that I want to loop over, parse some information from the "Identifiers" module and then loop again within their list of "Sample attributes" to store them in a file, including for each of them both their "Tag" and "Value". These data are not standardized (ie the attributes' tags don't always match) so I want to output all of them for each Sample. I wrote this piece of code that worked with other XML files with the same structure:

```
# import the XML file
e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('file.xml').getroot()
# create output file
file = open('output.txt','w')
# loop over all "Sample" modules
for i in range(0,len(e.findall('EXPERIMENT_PACKAGE/SAMPLE'))):
    node = e.findall('EXPERIMENT_PACKAGE/SAMPLE')[i]
    accession = node.find('IDENTIFIERS/PRIMARY_ID').text
    sample = node.find('IDENTIFIERS/EXTERNAL_ID').text                
    # loop over the list of attributes and print 'accession', 'sample', and for each attribute, 'tag' and 'value'   
    for attribute in node.findall('SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTES/SAMPLE_ATTRIBUTE'):
           file.write(accession + '\t' + sample + '\t' + str(attribute.find('TAG').text) + '\t' + 
           str(attribute.find('VALUE').text) + '\n')
file.close()
```

This code worked in the past, and it should give an output such as:

```
> ERS1486582    SAMEA36350668   collection date 2011
> ERS1486582    SAMEA36350668   geographic location USA 
> ...
```

But with this particular XML file is giving me an error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

I guess some element has None value? How could I try to check if the elements are not NoneType before writing out their values? I've tried adding an 'if' condition like:

```
if attribute.find('VALUE').text is not None:
```

within the second 'for' loop (before writing in the output file) but it's not working either. Thanks very much for your help and sorry if I didn't express myself clearly.

Comment: A diagnostic like this means that you are trying to access `element.text` when the value of `element` itself is `None`. Therefore, even a test such as `element.text is not None` will raise an exception because it implies that Python must look for the `text` value for `None`, which is impossible.

Comment: I just realised I didn't answer your question. If you want to check that an element exists you can indeed use `if element`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I ran the code in the question and got the expected output.

Comment: Thanks Bill! I used an `if attribute.finde('VALUE')` condition and seemed to get around it. 

And yes, mzjn, sorry, this was just an example, the real XML is too big to explore by eye and has 40,000+ "Sample" entries.